# How to use bootstrap along with Ionic in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, bootstrap-4

I have created an angular project with Ionic framework, but I want to use Bootstrap also, How I Use that,

I have installed the bootstrap and changed the **angular.json** file like below:

```
        "styles": [
          {
            "input": "src/assets/styles/theme/variables.scss"
          },
          {
            "input": "src/assets/styles/global.scss"
          },
          {
            "input": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          }
        ],
```

After Changing like above I am able to use Bootstrap components but they are not responsive,

MY HTML:

```
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Dark</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
```

My output:
[image: output]

i.e Buttons are occupying the full-screen width

What I feel is Bootstrap is not responsive after adding with Ionic framework correct me If I am wrong, I don't no how to proceed further, can anyone help me.

If I comment all the below files in variable.scss then the bootstrap is working fine, but I want to use bootstrap and Ionic together

```
      /* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
      @import "~@ionic/angular/css/core.css";

      // /* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
      @import "~@ionic/angular/css/normalize.css";
      @import "~@ionic/angular/css/structure.css";
      @import "~@ionic/angular/css/typography.css";
      @import '~@ionic/angular/css/display.css';

      /* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
      @import "~@ionic/angular/css/padding.css";
      @import "~@ionic/angular/css/float-elements.css";
      @import "~@ionic/angular/css/text-alignment.css";
      @import "~@ionic/angular/css/text-transformation.css";
      @import "~@ionic/angular/css/flex-utils.css";
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap with ionic ?!, seems not good for me, ionic provides you with a huge number of components and a grid for responsiveness, if you want more components , you can make it on your own which i recommend, if you insist on using bootstrap, try using [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) or [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation#getting-started) , and again, i don't recommend using bootstrap with ionic, it's a bad practice

Comment: He is asking a question not your opinion on good and bad practices. And if you want to use ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap you need to include css of bootstrap for components to display properly. So you need to solve the issue in the question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)

[Tutorial](https://edupala.com/how-to-install-bootstrap-in-ionic-4-and-above/)